# String Length restricting to add characters in textbox in .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, string-length

I am trying to do client side validations for string length using data Annotation so I have added [Stringlength(100,ErrorMessage="Name Exceeds length 100")] to model property.

I want to add more than 100 characters also it should show errormessage on UI but it is not showing error message and accepting only 100 characters.
Anyone have idea why string length is restricting to add characters and not showing message?

**Model Property**

[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "ABCD")]
 public string Name { get; set; }

**MVC Control-**

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)

**Textbox Rendered-**

```html
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="ABCD" data-val-length-max="100" id="Name" maxlength="100" name="Name" type="text" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see that `maxlength="100"` exists in the  rendered Textbox, which prevents you from typing more characters. You can use js to remove it.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#Name").removeAttr("maxlength")
})
</script>
```